# What Magento 2 directories can be safely deleted from a production deployment?

Tags: magento2

We're using a CI process to deploy Magento 2 to a server when a change happens in the repository. Due to the sheer size of the Magento 2 codebase, this can take quite some time.

Improving the CI process is not really an option in our organization, so I'm wondering if I can delete some of the Magento 2 files that aren't really needed in a production deployment.

The first ones that come to mind are `/dev` and `/phpserver`.

Questions:

1. Will deleting these directories cause issues in production?
2. Are there other directories we can remove to save time and space?